# Value is not getting inserted in the array,array returns blank values

Tags: arrays, node.js, promise, sequelize.js

I have following code , the problem is that obj is not inserted in the array arr.

```
let arr=[];
let frommilisec=1620000000;
let tomilisec=4680000000;
let slotmilisec=900000;
while(frommilisec<=tomilisec)
{
    let timeslot_milisec=frommilisec+slotmilisec;

    clinicslotsfunc(timeslot_milisec,maximumAppointment,clinicid,dated).then(results=>
    {
        let obj=results[0];
        console.log(obj);   // this displays { slot: '12:30:00', isbooked: 1 }
        arr.push(obj);
    });    
    console.log(arr)   //this logs blank array
    frommilisec=frommilisec+timeslot_milisec;
}
```

`results[0]` contains data `{ slot: '12:30:00', isbooked: 1 }`

Comment: `clinicslotsfunc` might be async function. Try logging arr just after arr.push inside then block

Comment: I would really recommend getting used to debugger tools for such cases. Here's a link to a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H0XScE08hy8

Comment: @Sunil it logs arr after arr.push. I want to return this arr .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promise is an async operation, so you need to `await` a result of asynchronous operation:

```
async yourmethod()
{
    let arr=[];
    let frommilisec=1620000000;
    let tomilisec=4680000000;
    let slotmilisec=900000;
    while(frommilisec<=tomilisec)
    {
        let timeslot_milisec=frommilisec+slotmilisec;    
        let result = await clinicslotsfunc(timeslot_milisec
            , maximumAppointment, clinicid, dated);

        arr.push(result);
    });    
    console.log(arr);
    frommilisec=frommilisec+timeslot_milisec;
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: How can I return arr from this async yourmethod() ?

Comment: It returns Promise { <pending> }.

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth could you show result of `console.log(result)` and `console.log(result.data)`?

Comment: For console.log(result) it logs { slot: '18:15:00', isbooked: 1 } and for console.log(result.data) it logs undefined.

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth ok. Now we see that result is got from the API. Could you say what `console.log(arr);` shows after `while` loop?

Comment: It logs [
  { slot: '10:15:00', isbooked: 1 },
  { slot: '20:30:00', isbooked: 1 }
]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204826/discussion-between-stepup-and-prabhjot-singh-kainth).

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth thanks for marking my reply. What was the problem? Why does your method return `Promise<pending>`?

Comment: Because clinicslotsfunc itself was a promise,Sequelize query. It was waiting for the sequelize promise to finish. That`s why. Anyways thanks for giving your time .

Answer (score -1):

Since **clinicslotsfunc** returns a promise (is asynchronously run), the '.then' part gets executed in the future at some time and therefore the obj is pushed to the array in future at some time provided the promise doesn't reject.

Now since you are doing console.log(arr); after this asynchronous task, it is empty because the **clinicslotsfunc.then()** would not have run immediately. So your array is always logged empty because the array will be filled in future.

Comment: That I know , I want value to be inserted into the array.