# Set value of global variable inside async function or inside promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

**Firstly I want to ask if this is possible or not,Setting value to global variable inside async function or promise?**

If yes then why does every available tutorial/website uses console.log(results) in the tutorial but never uses it to assign it to variable.

For example:

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve('foo');
});
let myval="";
promise1.then(function(value) {
 myval=value;
  console.log(value); // this logs "foo"
});

console.log(myval); //this logs blank
```

Comment: Are you aware that `//this logs blank` is called before `//this logs "foo"` because of the delay caused by the promise?

Comment: Yes I am pretty much aware of that. My question is how can I assign value to variable myval (assume myval to be global).

Comment: the code is not the problem but the interpretation is. If you need the global variable set to something inside the promise, there are two ways to handle this

- Wait for some random time which is obviously not 100% correct as it may or maynot work. Depends on how much time promise takes to resolve
- If you really need global variable, make sure you use them in the promise chain. So in your example instead of doing console log outside promise chain, do it as a next then and use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to access the changed version of `myval` (that is, execute your code after the assignment inside the Promise has been done), you need to either follow up with yet another `then`, or do anything else that'd put your code in the event queue after the assignment.

```js
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve('foo');
});
let myval="a";
promise1.then(function(value) {
 myval=value;
  console.log(value); // this logs "foo"
});

setTimeout(() => console.log(myval), 0); // logs "foo"
```

```js
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve('foo');
});
let myval="a";
promise1.then(function(value) {
 myval=value;
  console.log(value); // this logs "foo"
}).then(function() {
    console.log(myval) // logs "foo"
});
```

And an await example, probably the one you're looking for:

- wrap everything into an immediately invoked async function, so we can use `await` inside
- save the `.then` promise into a variable (you can, obviously, omit that variable altogether and `await` directly)
- `await` that promise before your `console.log`

```js
(async () => {
    var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve('foo');
    });
    let myval="";
    var thenedPromise = promise1.then(function(value) {
     myval=value;
      console.log(value); // this logs "foo"
    });

    await thenedPromise; // wait before the promise generated by "then" is resolved

    console.log(myval); // logs "foo"
})();
```

Comment: how can I then use `myval` later in my script of you don't use the async? or is that impossible?

Comment: @BrianWiley It's best to use async/await. You can't use it "later in the script", only inside `.then` callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

That would change the global variable `myval` to `'foo'` but by the time `console.log(myval);` is called the promised has not yet been resolved because of the timeout and even if you resolve the promise immediately it will still only change it after the `console.log(myval);` has run because the promise will be queued as a [microtask](https://javascript.info/microtask-queue).

I would add a setTimeout to wait for the assignment or a setInterval to check for when it happens.

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
resolve('foo');});
let myval="";
promise1.then(function(value) {
  myval=value;
  console.log(value); // this logs "foo"
});

setTimeout(() => console.log(myval), 1000); //this logs 'foo'
```

Comment: My question is how can I assign the value to myval . I know about promises.

Comment: That is what my answer confirms that it would still change/assign the value to `myval`. If you want to use it then you have to wait for the assignment to take place. For example checking it in a `setInterval`

Comment: I have updated my question, I have removed setTimeout . Still it won`t set value to myval.

Comment: You are not getting my question. Just forget about console.log(myval). I am asking how to assign the value to myval ??? How can I do this??

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth You are assigning to myval, but the bottom console.log happens before the value is assigned (because the promise.then is executed not immediately, but put into the queue - everything in .then is executed AFTER the main code). Read up about Node's asynchrony.

Comment: @JohnSmith I understand that thing pretty well. I want to use myval variable somewhere else in my code , but at that point also it is blank . Also I have used await still  doesnot works.

Comment: See this question of mine also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59476582/value-is-not-getting-inserted-in-the-array-array-returns-blank-values/59476618?noredirect=1#comment105131574_59476618

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth seconding the above comment by John Smith, your program does what you are trying to do, it's just your testing/debugging that isn't working as intended

Answer (score 2):

It is all about javascript's async behavior. See the below snippet and notice the execution sequence. `value` is already assigning to `myval` after resolving the promise. In your case, you just need to maintain a flag whether that particular promise is resolved or not then after if you will try to get the value of `myval` variable you will your desired output. And yes, it is one of the many ways of achieving this.

```js
let myval="";
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve('foo');
});
promise1.then(function(value) {
    myval=value;
    console.log("Value :" + value);
    console.log("myval after promise : " + myval);
});

console.log("myval before promise : " + myval);
```