# How can I assign value in "then" in Node JS in a global variable to use later

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api

```
let city;
let c;

async function getCity() {
  let apiKey = '9ddf7197ff9633535259c99aa0716c329981d1514f05e2e1e2015803';
  let response = await fetch(`https://api.ipdata.co?api-key=${apiKey}`);
  let data = await response.json();
  city = data.city;
  return city;
}

getCity().then(
    function (value) {
        c = value.city;
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
);

console.log(c);
```

How do I assign a value to a global variable so that it can be use anywhere in the code. As I tried this method but I am getting "undefined" as my solution from console.log.

Comment: You can use window, window is a global object in the browser but you shouldn't use global variables at all

Comment: You're assigning the value just fine to a global variable. The problem is that you attempt to use it immediately, not "later". This is why assigning variables asynchronously is a bad idea - you never know when they will have been assigned.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need to `await` when calling the function `getCity()`. I wasn't able to get a value, but I fixed the error. Try this:

```
let city;

async function getCity() {
  let apiKey = 'api_key';
  let response = await fetch(`https://api.ipdata.co?api-key=${apiKey}`);
  let data = await response.json();
  city = data.city;
  return city;
}

getCity().then(
    function (value) {
        console.log(value)
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
);
```

Comment: I am getting 'undefined' instead of the city name.

Comment: @PrabhatRai Because the function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Then how do I get the solution. I am stuck with this and don't know what to do?

Comment: Can you use the api key that I added and then try the code to get the city?

Comment: @PrabhatRai worked for me with the API key

Comment: I am getting 'undefined' instead of city name.

Comment: @PrabhatRai Did you add the `return city;` at the end of the function?

Comment: I didn't do it. It was not in the solution provided. But now I saw the edit. Thank you @ajdejesus

Comment: But can you help me get it in a variable where I don't have to use "then" and use the variable later

Comment: @PrabhatRai I'll try and get back with any update

Comment: Ok but if you can hurry a bit then it would be helpful. Thank you once again for your help.

Comment: It is difficult to set global variables with async functions, since the async function will always run after everything else has been executed. You can try the solutions stated here: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59477505/set-value-of-global-variable-inside-async-function-or-inside-promise