# Couldn't update variable outside .then async function

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, promise

I am trying to check the progress of a listening session stored in AsyncStorage on React Native.
My aim is to show progress (stored in a form of a number) against total lines (number).

I have this working code that outputs the total lines (sourced from a different API using fetch, not the problem here), but I can't seem to get the variable i declared outside of async function to be updated inside of the .then block, to be used in the return statment below.

Here's the (half)working code:

```
    ....//other existing codes in a React functional component

    //this is the async code that checks the store data in AsyncStorage
    const checkProgressListening = async(name) => {
        let response = await AsyncStorage.getItem(name+'-LISTENING_SESSION')
        let json = await JSON.parse(response)
        return json;
    }

    //this is the code that will be rendered in RNUILIB GridList
    const renderItemModule = ({item, index}) => {
        //declaring a variable outside of the .then function block below
        let progress = null;

        checkProgressListening(item.englishName).then(async (data) => {
            if(data != null){
                progress = data.number
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })

        return (
            <Text>{progress}/{totalnumberoflines}</Text>
        )
    }

    ...//other existing code
    return(
        <GriddList
            ...
            data={dataItems}
            renderItem={renderItemModule}
        />
    )
```

I tried to re-assign the variable `progress` with a new value from inside of the .then async block, but unsuccessful so far.

I've referred to this article on StackOverflow, but still couldn't get it working
[Set value of global variable inside async function or inside promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59477505/set-value-of-global-variable-inside-async-function-or-inside-promise)

Comment: This exact question is asked dozens of times a day on Stackoverflow [How to return values from async functions using async-await from function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938266/how-to-return-values-from-async-functions-using-async-await-from-function)

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a timing issue.

In the `renderItemModule` function, the return statement executes without waiting for the promise to resolve. What is happening is that

1. `progress` if defined with the value `null`
2. The `checkProgressListening` function is called and the code *begins* accessing the `AsyncStorage`
3. The `renderItemModule` function returns with the value of `progress` still `null`.
4. The async function attached to the promise executes and sets the value of `progress`, but only after `renderItemModule` has returned `null`. This is because the `renderItemModule` function isn't waiting for the callback to set the value of `progress` before it is returned.

You want to consider making `renderItemModule` asynchronous:

```
const renderItemModule = async ({item, index}) => {
    let progress = null;

    let data = await checkProgressListening(item.englishName);
    if (data != null){
        progress = data.number;
    }

    return (
        <Text>{progress}/{totalnumberoflines}</Text>
    )
}
```

Because this is an `async` function and it uses `await` when calling `checkProgressListening`, the function does not return until the promise is resolved.

Unfortunately, it might get a bit tricky to integrate an asynchronous version of `checkProgressListening` and may mean that you need to make many more functions asynchronous.